# How to open a file in python when using the relative path from the scripts location

Tags: python, file, text, path

I have a directory Structure as such

```
MainFolder/unitTest/test.py
MainFolder/run.py
MainFolder/model/file.py
MainFolder/config/config.conf
```

Inside file.py i am trying to open a file

```
f = open('config/config.conf', 'r')
```

Normally the file.py  is called from run.py. The current working  directory is that of the run.py. so if i want to access  the config file . i go to config folder and then to the file `'config/config.conf'`
If i want to run it from the unit test i need to go up one level and then into the config folder.`'../config/config.conf'`

Is there a way that when opening a file , it starts looking for the file from where the file.py is located  so that regardless of where the file.py is called from i can access the file  as `../config/config.conf`

This is going to be hosted on a remote server so i cant give it the full path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just create a file, e.g. pwd.py in your project root directory.

```
import os

PWD = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

then in your modules:

```
from pwd import PWD

f = open('%s/config/config.conf' % PWD, 'r')
```

Comment: This works. 

Tbh i find it a bit stupid that there is no way to go from the path of the file the file is actually in. But this does the job

Answer (score 0):

What you need may be to organize your codes in [Python modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package). It helps you design/access/manage each file in a Pythonic way.

To solve your problem, you can work around by setting MainFolder as the current working directory with `os.chdir` at the beginning of the `file.py`. It means that you need to have the full path of MainFolder either by using `os.path.getcwd` in `run.py` to find out or storing it in config file when deployed.